# Jenkins Maven Proxy - Can't Download Dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, proxy

I have a project which I can build locally using mvn clean install.` However if I try in Jenkins I get error when it tries to download dependency from pom

Clicking on dependency link in console output produces an xml so it does exist. It is the same for all other dependecies in pom. I am using a proxy and tried to change jenkins.xml in Jenkins folder:

```
<arguments>-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyport -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

Also have entered proxy in Manage Plugins > Advanced.

Do I need to configure something else?

Answer (score 2):

You Jenkins user will be running maven, that maven installation will have a settings.xml, you will need to add the proxy details to this file.

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Also check the maven configuration in Jenkins.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_maven_setup.htm

Jenkins just delegate to maven, you should get the same behavior from the command line with the Jenkins user and correct maven install.

Comment: Yes, I have the proxy in this settings file. And if I remove it and try to run locally, I get the same error as in Jenkins so it must be something to do with this proxy. I wonder where else I might need to put the proxy info